# SignalR - how to signal to front-end to update after an entry has been saved successfully to the db?

Tags: c#, signalr, asp.net-core-webapi

I have Asp.Net Core 6 Web Admin Api.

I have have a table with entities and an enpoint to add a new entity.

I want when one user creates a new entity - the others to see this in real time. That is why I am adding `SignalR`.

I want to signal to the clients to update AFTER the entity has been saved successfully to the database.

What is the best way to do it?

I see [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/modules/aspnet-core-signalr/3-how-signalr-works) that there is `IHubContext<NotificationHub>`.

I believe in my scenario the best way would be to inject the context in the Controller and call it in the action AFTER the entity is saved to the DB?

Is there a better solution to the problem?

```
[ApiController]
public class ItemsController : ControllerBase
{
    private readonly IHubContext<NotificationHub> _hubContext;
    private readonly IRepository<Item> _repo;

    public ItemsController (IHubContext<NotificationHub> hubContext, IRepository<Item> repo)
    {
        _hubContext = hubContext;
        _repo = repo;
    }

    [HttpPost]
    public async Task<IActionResult> AddItem(ItemDto item)
    {
        var id = await _repo.AddAsync(item);
        if (id is null)
        {
            return BadRequest();
        }

        await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("NotificationReceived", id);

        return Created(item.Id);
    }
```

Comment: are you listening for the 'NotificationReceived' event on the frontend?

Comment: Yes, I am listening for this event on the FE.

Comment: sorry just spotted this, you might just need to await _hubContext.Clients.All.SendAsync("NotificationReceived", id); to ensure it runs and isnt just skipped over as its an async method.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubcontext?view=aspnetcore-6.0#inject-a-strongly-typed-hubcontext) this is the right way - inject IHubContext<> where we need it. I failed to see this page at first.

Maybe the best option is to use a strongly-typed HubContext to avoid errors with string names.

```
public class ChatController : Controller
{
    private IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient> _strongChatHubContext { get; }

    public ChatController(IHubContext<ChatHub, IChatClient> chatHubContext)
    {
      _strongChatHubContext = chatHubContext;
    }

    public async Task SendMessage(string user, string message)
    {
        await _strongChatHubContext.Clients.All.ReceiveMessage(user, message);
    }
}
```